# Multi line Text widget gives me an overflown error

Tags: flutter

I have a ConstrainedBox which has a listView and its children has the following widget:
(I need all the column and rows. removed everything that wasn't necessary to reproduce the issue.)

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'this is some longggggggggggggggggggggggg texttttttttt that gets overflown',
              style: textStyle,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 5,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

The issue is, the text doesn't go to the next line. I tried adding `Expand` widget to the text widget, to the column widget and row widget, and when i do that it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole inner `Column` in an `Expanded` widget. You need to constrain the `Text` widget horizontally. Using `Expanded` in a `Column` will constrain it vertically, while constraining using it in a `Row` will constrain it horizontally and tell `Text` where to wrap.

```dart
return Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'this is some longggggggggggggggggggggggg texttttttttt that gets overflown',
                style: textStyle,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 5,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```